# C++ implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I have written this simple code for Tic Tac Toe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void draw_board(const std::vector< std::vector<char> >& vec)
{
    std::cout << "    0   1   2  \n";
    std::cout << "  +---+---+---+\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " ;
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << "| " << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "|";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "  +---+---+---+\n";
    }
}

void enter(int row, int col, char ch, std::vector< std::vector<char> >& vec)
{
    vec[row][col] = ch;
}

bool check(const std::vector< std::vector<char> >& vec)
{
    //to check diagonals
    if ((vec[0][0] == 'X' && vec[1][1] == 'X' && vec[2][2] == 'X')
        || (vec[0][2] == 'X' && vec[1][1] == 'X' && vec[2][0] == 'X'))
        {
            std::cout << "Player X won this game\n";
            return true;
        }
    else if ((vec[0][0] == 'O' && vec[1][1] == 'O' && vec[2][2] == 'O')
             || (vec[0][2] == 'O' && vec[1][1] == 'O' && vec[2][0] == 'O'))
             {
                std::cout << "Player O won this game\n";
                return true;
             }

    //to check horizonatal and vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((vec[i][0] == 'X' && vec[i][1] == 'X' && vec[i][2] == 'X')
              || (vec[0][i] == 'X' && vec[1][i] == 'X' && vec[2][i] == 'X'))
              {
                  std::cout << "Player X won this game\n";
                  return true;
              }
        else if((vec[i][0] == 'O' && vec[i][1] == 'O' && vec[i][2] == 'O')
              || (vec[0][i] == 'O' && vec[1][i] == 'O' && vec[2][i] == 'O'))
              {
                  std::cout << "Player O won this game\n";
                  return true;
              }
    }
}

void start(std::vector< std::vector<char> >& vec)
{
    int row, col, res = 0;
    char ch;

    std::vector<int> index = {0, 1, 2};

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++)
        {
            vec[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9;)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i%2 == 0)
        {
            ch = 'X';
            std::cout << "Chance to enter X\n";
        }
        else
        {
            ch = 'O';
            std::cout << "Chance to enter O\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Enter row number ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << "Enter column number ";
        std::cin >> col;
        if (vec[row][col] == ' ' || vec[row][col] == ' ')
        {
            enter(row, col, ch, vec);
            draw_board(vec);
            if ( i >= 2)
            {
                res = check(vec);
                if (res == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "This position already contains a character\n";
        }

    }
    if (res == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "This game draws\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector<char> > board(3, std::vector<char>(3));
    draw_board(board);
    start(board);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Check your inputs in `enter()`

You don't check that the user entered a valid vector index. For example, if I enter a `3` as the row and/or column number the program crashes. You should reject an input if the user enters an invalid row and/or column number (like you do if the user selects a space that is already taken).

#### All control paths of `check()` should return a value

You only ever `return true` in `check()`. If none of the check conditions are true then you should explicitly `return false` at the end of the function.

#### Use the correct type for indexing

You have for loops like `for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)`, which compare the signed integer `i` to the unsigned integer `vec.size()`. Use `std::vector< std::vector<char> >::size_type`.

#### Use a type alias / type definition for the `std::vector< std::vector<char> >` container

Use a type alias like `using container = std::vector< std::vector<char> >;` if your compiler supports it, otherwise use a type definition like `typedef std::vector< std::vector<char> > container;`. You can put it after the `#include` statements so you can use it for all your functions. This is useful for a couple of reasons:

1. It's a shorter name for the container. This comes in handy when referring to the container and/or its `size_type`, for example: `container::size_type` is shorter and easier to read than `std::vector< std::vector<char> >::size_type`.
2. It's easier to change the container. You may decide later to use a `std::array` instead, in which case you only need to modify the `using` statement rather than all instances of `std::vector< std::vector<char> >`.

Answer (score 4):

- Don't declare more than one variable per line
- You can skip your initialization code for the vector and just do it when you declare it: `std::vector< std::vector<char> > board(3, std::vector<char>(3, ' '));`
- You confused [rows and columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces)
- You don't return `false` at the end of your check function which makes the game end after 3 turns.
- `index` does not seem to be used?